# Deleting shape in drawRect method? - ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a rectangle drawn using `drawRect` method. I need to update this rectangle.

But I don't know how to create an instance of it.

I need to delete the previously drawn rectangle (or) change the frame of the previously drawn rectangle.

How can I do this?

Comment: In drawRect you would usually just clear the rect and then draw over it. Please add your code.

Comment: you need to redraw whole drawing with modified data

Answer (score 0):

The system keeps track of which part of your view it thinks is “dirty” (needs to be drawn).  When the view is first created, the entire view is dirty.  When you send `setNeedsDisplay` to the view, that marks the entire view dirty.  If you send `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`, the specified `CGRect` is added to the part of the view that is considered dirty.

Before the system sends your view the `drawRect:` message, it clears the entire dirty region of the view to the view's background color.  So if you send `setNeedsDisplay` to your view when you want to erase the previously drawn rectangle, you don't need to worry about erasing your rectangle in `drawRect:`; the system has already erased it for you.  But it also means that if there was anything in the dirty region that you **didn't** want erased, **you must draw it again** before returning from `drawRect:`.

Comment: ok.. suppose I have a subUIView inside the bounds of this rectangle. If I  do clearRect for that rectangle, will the subUIView get removed?